# how to reset variable back to default?

Tags: javascript

I have created javascript code, where I have two circles and if you click on the right one you score 1 point. I want to create a button that resets the game by resetting my var back to 0.

This is my code so far

```
var result = document.getElementById("result");
    var head = document.getElementById("circle");
    var tails = document.getElementById("circle2");
    var win = document.getElementById("win");
    var loss = document.getElementById("loss");
    var winsorloss = 1;
    var winsorloss2 = 1;
    var winsorloss3 =1;
     var winsorloss4 = 1;


    head.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var num = Math.random()
        if (num > .50) {

            result.innerHTML="You clicked Heads and the result was Heads You won";
            win.innerHTML= winsorloss++
        }else{
            result.innerHTML="You clicked Heads and the result was Tails You lost";
            loss.innerHTML = winsorloss2++;
        }


    })

    tails.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var num2 = Math.random()
        if (num2 < .50) {

            result.innerHTML="You clicked Tails and the result was Tails You won";
            win.innerHTML=winsorloss3 = winsorloss++
        }else{
            result.innerHTML="You clicked Tails and the result was Heads You lost";
            loss.innerHTML=winsorloss4 =winsorloss2++;
        }


    })
```

Originally, I had the following code for the reset, but didn't work properly

```
function erase(){
    result.innerHTML="";
    win.innerHTML = winsorloss = 0;
    loss.innerHTML = winsorloss2 = 0;

}
```

Comment: The initial values in your script are `1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial values of your variables are all `1`, not `0`. The reason that works initially is because you're using post-increment when you update them, so you update the HTML with the old value, and then increment the variables. It would be better to initialize them to `0` and use pre-increment, so that the variables contain the same thing that you're showing in the results.

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var head = document.getElementById("circle");
var tails = document.getElementById("circle2");
var win = document.getElementById("win");
var loss = document.getElementById("loss");
var winsorloss = 0;
var winsorloss2 = 0;
var winsorloss3 = 0;
var winsorloss4 = 0;

head.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var num = Math.random()
  if (num > .50) {

    result.innerHTML = "You clicked Heads and the result was Heads You won";
    win.innerHTML = ++winsorloss;
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "You clicked Heads and the result was Tails You lost";
    loss.innerHTML = ++winsorloss2;
  }
})

tails.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var num2 = Math.random()
  if (num2 < .50) {

    result.innerHTML = "You clicked Tails and the result was Tails You won";
    win.innerHTML = winsorloss3 = ++winsorloss;
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "You clicked Tails and the result was Heads You lost";
    loss.innerHTML = winsorloss4 = ++winsorloss2;
  }
})

function reset() {
  winsorloss = winsorloss2 = winsorloss3 = winsorloss4 = 0;
  win.innerHTML = "0";
  loss.innerHTML = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple example

```js
var default_value=()=>({
a:1,
b:2,
})

var bill=default_value();
bill.a=7;
console.log(bill)
console.log("---------------reset all value---------------")
bill=default_value();

console.log(bill)
```